# Unique UITableViewCell with different functionality

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my project there is a requirement to show Each UITableViewCell as Unique one. Say if there are 10 cells all 10 cell will be having different number of subviews associated with it. To achieve this I m creating new cells each and every time meaning I m not doing `dequeCell:`. Every time I m allocating new cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"abc"];
    return cell;
}
```

Is it ok to proceed with this or is there any better alternate approach.

And some of the cell needs to download Image from URL for which I use following snippet

```
[imgSection setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:column.icon]]]];
```

Please help me out with solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with unique reuse identifier

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString* _cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RowIdent%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
    TableViewCell* _cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:_cellIdentifier];
    if (!_cell)
    {
        _cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                     reuseIdentifier:_cellIdentifier];
    }
    // do awesome
    return _cell;
}
```

you can make cell identifier depended on row number. in this case reuse identifier will work properly, but all your cell will be unique.

**UPDATE:**

for downloading image try to use `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h` with

```
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure;
```

method (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

hope it helps.

Comment: UDID string generates new Identifier every time. If I generate Identifier with respect to index path It would be more crisp.

Comment: i updated my answer with your case: you can make cell identifier depended on row number. in this case reuse identifier will work properly, but all your cell will be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Although you want each cell to be different, you don't want a new cell every time `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called - if a user scrolls away from a cell, then scrolls back again, they should still see the same cell.  You could achieve this by using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` as normal, but using `[indexPath description]` as the `reuseIdentifier`.

Comment: yes! you are right. Image downloading logic should alos init method itself you mean?

Comment: No, you want to download the images on a different thread.  Put them into an `NSCache` or save them to disk, then when each one downloads reload the cell at the appropriate index path.